# Using boolean indexing with Groupby() in jupyter, python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and I have filtered and sorted out the data and got to the desired answer aswell but im trying to do it in a single line.
Here the sample filtered dataframe:

```
designer
AMD                   16
ARM                    3
Acorn                  4
Acorn/DEC/Apple        1
Apple                 10
Bell Labs              1
DEC WRL                1
Fujitsu               10
Garrett AiResearch     1
```

code to get it:

`df = cpu.groupby('Designer')['Processor'].nunique()` 
I'm struggling to get values that are greater than or equal to 2.

the code I used to get values to achieve it:

`df[df >= 2].count()` 
Is there a way to combine these 2 lines of code into 1

I've tried using boolean indexing but I get lost.
the code i tried:

`cpu[cpu.groupby('designer')['processor'].nunique()>1].count()` 
but it gives me the error that I understand. I tried using  cpu['designer'] instead of just cpu but the error persists.

Comment: `cpu.groupby(['Designer'])['Processor'].nunique().ge(1).sum()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and a callable (lambda) to perform your filtering without intermediate variable:

```
(cpu.groupby('Designer')['Processor'].nunique()  
    .loc[lambda df: df >= 2].count()
)
```